# How does Dropbox Open button work?

Tags: javascript, dropbox

In February 2015 Dropbox released a new feature that allowed you to trigger the local opening of a file from their web interface:
https://blogs.dropbox.com/dropbox/2015/02/new-way-to-open-dropbox-files/

More information is here:

- https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/8571
- https://www.dropbox.com/help/8572

Here is an example of the Open button visible from the context menu:

[image]

And here is the brief display of the popup that is apparently connecting to the sync client:

[image]

It's clear that the Dropbox sync client must be installed, so you have some native local code running, which allows for some fancy stuff that would be impossible with just in-browser Javascript, but somehow the browser page is able to do some unexpected things:

1. selectively display the Open button based on information from the
   sync client (whether it's on and whether the file exists locally)
2. trigger, by clicking on the button, an action by the sync client
   (opening the file in its default app, or opening the folder in
   Explorer/Finder)

By what technical mechanism do these two things work?

Comment: Probably something along the lines of `NPAPI`.

Comment: It would take a fair amount of reverse engineering to find the exact channel DropBox uses to make this happen, but there are multiple possible ways. Do you want to know how they do it, or how you could do it?

Comment: Both... intellectual curiosity and also wondering if I can co-opt their system to trigger the opening of a local folder in Dropbox from my own web service.

Comment: @Alagaros - NPAPI itself is now disabled by default in Chrome, I think.  And btw- I don't have any sort of Dropbox extensions in Chrome (or any other browser).  It's quite mysterious.

Comment: No Extensions nor Plugins, for clarity.  chrome://plugins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but probably something like this:

1. The sync client knows everything about local file existence.
2. The sync client sends that info to the sync server, so the server knows too.
3. The Dropbox web page can then selectively show the open button.
4. Upon clicking the open button, the web page contacts the sync server, which in turn sends a message to the sync client to "open that file".
5. The sync client opens that file. On a Mac this would be a simple `open [path]` shell command.

Nothing fancy in the browser.

Comment: Your explanation skips the key steps.  eg- in step 3, how does the web page selectively display the link based on what the sync client knows?  Specifically, what's the mechanism for them to talk to each other?  It would seem like pure Javascript shouldn't have a way to do it, and there are no plugins or extensions running in the browser as far as I can tell.

Comment: What I tried to outline is that the web page doesn't talk with the sync client, it just talks with the server. That should be possible with commonplace AJAX.

Comment: Hmm... implying that even the "open file" commands goes from browser to server and then to sync client.  Certainly that's possible, and would explain the delay when you choose to open the file... takes longer than if it were just a local trigger.

Comment: If I put my wifi off and click on the link, it opens on my desktop. I dont think any network call is in play here.